# why can't i returns values inside thread function?

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers

I am writing a function to create thread and a function for waiting . but I got some error like

```
main.c:: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

and

```
function.c: In function ‘create_thread’:
function.c:: warning: function returns address of local variable
function.c: In function ‘wait_thread’:
function.c:: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘pthread_join’ makes integer   from pointer without a cast
```

my code is here :

main function :

```
------------some declartions------
pthread_t **thid =NULL;
thid = create_thread(argv,count);
wait_thread(thid,count);
----------some code-----------------
```

in my function file :

```
pthread_t *  create_thread(char *argv[],
                            int count)
{
 pthread_t thid[count];
 -------some codes-------------
 status = pthread_create(&thid[index],NULL,file_op,(void*)mystruct);
  -------------------------- 
  return thid;

}

 void wait_thread(pthread_t **thid,int count)
 {
   ------some codes-----------
   ret = pthread_join(thid[index],&retval);

 }
```

Is it any declaration of pointer in correct ? why I can't return values from the thread function ? any problem in my code ?

Comment: What do you expect from this to do?

Comment: I am receving using **pointer ..then I got this function array in my new array .Is it ?

Comment: how can I get that ?

Answer (score 0):

Lets view the warnings one by one:

> main.c:: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

You are most probably getting this error here:

```
thid = create_thread(argv,count);
```

The reason is that `create_thread` returns an argument of type `pthread_t*` while `thid` is of type `pthread_t**`.

> function.c: In function ‘create_thread’:
>   function.c:: warning: function returns address of local variable

The warning says it all. `pthread_t thid[count];` is a local variable. So, `return thid;` returns the address of the first element of this array which will be invalid once the function `create_thread` exits.

> function.c: In function ‘wait_thread’:
>   function.c:: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘pthread_join’ makes integer   from pointer without a cast

The function `pthread_join` expects its first to be of type `pthread_t`. You give the argument `thid[index]` which is of type `pthread_t*`. This is what the compiler is warning about.